# How do i play a spritesheet when the song starts in Friday Night Funkin': Psych Engine?

Tags: lua

so i know how to spawn an animated sprite in lua, but the problem is 1: it starts while the 3,2,1 countdown happens, and 2: even if i use an event to trigger it it lags out so badly and the chart becomes off sync with the actual game itself, completely glitching it out, i have no idea how to stop the lag or another way to go about this, the sprite needs to disappear on command as well

using events, precaching it, nothing works